# C++ How do I format a line of text that contains variable integers so that it is right aligned within a given width?

Tags: c++, formatting, iomanip

The formatting goal is as follows

```
   Absolute value of the number you entered : 723
                 Square root of that number : 26.89
       Rounding this to the nearest integer : 27
  Two random numbers between 27 and 723 are : ...
```

This is my code as it stands

```
  cout << right << setw(50) << "Absolute value of the number you entered : " << absoluteValue << endl;
  cout << right << setw(50) << "Square root of that number : " << squareRoot << endl;
  cout << right << setw(50) << "Rounding this to the nearest integer : " << roundedSquareRoot << endl;
  cout << right << setw(50) << "Two random numbers between " << roundedSquareRoot << " and " << absoluteValue << " are : ";
```

When I run I get this

```
   Absolute value of the number you entered : 723
                 Square root of that number : 26.89
       Rounding this to the nearest integer : 27
                   Two random numbers between 27 and 723 are :
```

The bottom most line right align and setw() only apply to the first "text"
How do I make it apply to everything on that line?
Thanks

Edit: To be clear, I just want the bottom line to act like the top three.

Answer (score 2):

You need to present the last line as a single string.
Your best bet is to pre-build that string.

```
std::sstream  lastLineStream;
lastLineStream << "Two random numbers between " 
               << roundedSquareRoot << " and " 
               << absoluteValue << " are : ";
```

Now you can print it as a single string.

```
 cout << right << setw(50) << "Rounding this to the nearest integer : " << roundedSquareRoot << endl;
 cout << right << setw(50) << lastLineStream.str();
```

Note:

prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`.
They both do the same thing, then `std::endl` will flush the buffer. Manually flushing the buffer is usually the wrong thing to do.